# how we can pass uid of current user login from adapter to other activity

Tags: java, android, database, android-intent, parameter-passing

how we can pass uid of current user login from adapter to other activity  I am already passing the clicked item id from adapter to other activity that easy because I already print this id but I am confused about how to pass the uid of current user login please guide

```
//I have retrieve data in main activity of current user
 private void loadmyinfo() {
    DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    ref .orderByChild("uid").equalTo(firebaseAuth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String Nam=""+ds.child("name").getValue();
                // String accounttype=""+ds.child("account type").getValue();
                String Profile=""+ds.child("profileuser").getValue();
                String Email=""+ds.child("email").getValue();
                String cphone=""+ds.child("phone").getValue();

                nametx.setText(Nam);
                cphon.setText(cphone);
                nameemail.setText(Email);

                try {
                   /* Glide.with(ProfileeditsellerActivity.this)
                            .load(Profile)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                            .skipMemoryCache(true)
                            .into(profile);*/
                    Picasso.get().load(Profile).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile_gray).into(profile);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_profile_gray);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

adapter class

```
//In adapter class I have passed the id of clicked item but I want also to pass uid of current user 
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          /*  Intent intent=new Intent(context,BilActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",id);
            context.startActivity(intent);*/
            Intent intent=new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(),PayfeeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",id);
            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the current logged in firebase user from anywhere in your app using

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is passing the current user id you can use @huda Olayan 's answer but if you want a uid from a position in a list then you can use a localBroadcast to do so you will need to create an intent and pass the string in the intent like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("key-for-finding-broadcast");
intent.putExtra("uid", "uid");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

next you have to catch the broadcast and register the broadcastReciever and pass the intentFilter as the name "key-for-finding-broadcast". So you make a new BroadcastReceiver like so:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //to find the uid when its recieved you do the following
        String uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid");
    }
};
```

then you have to register so you can put this line in your onCreate Method:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(broadcastReciever, new IntentFilter("key-for-finding-broadcast"));
```